# Firebase security access sibling node's child

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have the following data structure

- data

  - users
  - counter

    - count

where count is any integer, I made the following security rule to allow adding users only if the count value is less than for example 5

```
"users": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "root.child('counter').child('count').val() < 5" 
}
```

but it shows me permission denied. Any other suggestions to access a child of sibling nodes?

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for `newData.parent().child('counter')...` instead of `root.child('counter')`. The different is that `newData` contains the... new data.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks so much, I spent hours trying to solve this :) Can you change it to answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
newData.parent().child('counter')...
```

instead of `root.child('counter')`. The difference is that [`newData`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/newdata.html) contains the... new data.